# How to return dictionary with occurrence per word in a string (Python)?

Tags: python, dictionary, return, find-occurrences

How can I make a function (given a string sentece) that returns a dictionary with each word as key and the number of occurrence as the value? (preferably without using functions like .count and .counter, basically as few shortcuts as possible.)

What I have so far doesn't seem to work and gives a key error, I have a small clue of why it doesn't work, but I'm not sure what to do to fix it. This is what I have for now:

```
def wordCount(sentence):
    myDict = {}
    mySentence = sentence.lower().split()

    for word in mySentence:
        if word in myDict:
           myDict[word] += 1
        else:
           myDict[word] = 1

    return myDict
wordCount("Hi hi hello")
print(myDict)
```

Comment: In `if word in mySentence:` probably you meant `if word in myDict:`.

Comment: Also, if this is not a programming exercise, you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to solve this problem: `Counter(sentence.lower().split())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been mixing up variables `mySentence` and `myDict` at one point.
You can also not use local variables outside of their scope. The following will work:

```
def wordCount(sentence):
    myDict = {}
    mySentence = sentence.lower().split()
    for word in mySentence:
        if word in myDict:
           myDict[word] += 1
        else:
           myDict[word] = 1
    return myDict

d = wordCount("Hi hi hello")  # assign the return value to a variable
print(d)  # so you can reuse it
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed that, but it still doesn't work though:/

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you call the function in your actual script within the function itself? I was assuming you just had the indentation wrong there.

Comment: Now i get an error saying "NameError: name 'myDict' is not defined", I call it outside the script, but still get an error

Comment: @Charlotte `myDict` is a local variable in your function. You cannot use it outside! I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it's solved now :)